# I need to find what archives are calling a specific css file, is there a tool for this?

Tags: html, css, request, stylesheet

I need to know what archives are calling a specific css file, is there a tool for this?

I have too many css files, and I want to concatenate to 1 or 2 stylesheets (max), but I need to know what files are calling them before deleting one by one. How can I do that? Is there a tool?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try just putting them all into 1 or 2 files, and then figuring out what is not being used by with the [find unused CSS rules feature in  Google Chrome Audit Tool](http://meeech.amihod.com/very-useful-find-unused-css-rules-with-google/).